# Why doesn't ShellExecute care about impersonation?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This is a question of inquiry - Why does [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) execute as the running user, ignoring my attempt to impersonate with [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx)?

I know that the expected way to do this is to create a helper process that will call ShellExecute, and then call [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx). [Here is my source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2010/02/01/why-can-t-i-elevate-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-while-using-createprocesswithlogonw.aspx).

I want to understand what it is about ShellExecuteEx that makes it ignore impersonation, though. Is it some sort of brokering to the current running Shell? What does it do? I can't find any information about this. Thanks in advance.

Please note that elevation isn't really what I'm asking about here, though it does make it interesting.

Comment: "Why" isn't quite the right question - it behaves that way because that's the documented behaviour.  As for "how", that's an implementation detail, subject to change.  (I suppose if you mean "why is that the documented behaviour" someone may know the answer.)

Comment: Still not sure what the answer here is, but I suspect it has something to do with running in the interactive session through the shell (explorer)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is puzzling.  API calls don't have to respect impersonation.  CreateProcess doesn't, in particular.